# Что делает команда: x.view(x.size(0), -1)?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, numpy, pytorch

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3)
        self.avg_pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))

        x = self.avg_pool(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1) #особенно эту строку не пойму, не силен в tensor numpy
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

```
x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
```

данная строка кода отвечает за изменение размерности тензора `x` таким образом что размерность первой оси (первого измерения) остается неизменной, а все остальные измерения упаковываются в одно, так чтобы получился 2D тензор с сохранением общего числа элементов.

Пример на чистом Numpy (`3D --> 2D`):

```
import numpy as np

# create 3D tensor
x = np.random.randint(10, size=(2,3,4))

print(x.shape)
# (2, 3, 4)

# reshape tensor 3D --> 2D
r = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)

print(r.shape)
# (2, 12)
```

Пример `4D --> 2D`:

```
In [22]: x = np.random.randint(10, size=(2,3,4,5))

In [23]: x.shape
Out[23]: (2, 3, 4, 5)

In [24]: x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1).shape
Out[24]: (2, 60)
```